# ngClick not registering when inside element used in directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a sidebar with an absolutely positioned anchor that when clicked, should activate an AngularJS directive to open/close the sidebar.

This works fine when the anchor is outside of the `aside` element but for positioning reasons, I want it inside. However, inside the element, I see no evidence that the click is ever handled.

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <aside data-slide-toggle="smToggleSidebar" data-slide-toggle-duration="100">
    <a ng-click="smToggleSidebar=!smToggleSidebar">&lang;</a>
    // content here
    </aside>
</div>
```

The directive is essentially:

```
.directive('slideToggle', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope:{
        isOpen: "=slideToggle"
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        var slideDuration = parseInt(attr.slideToggleDuration, 10) || 200;
        scope.$watch('isOpen', function(newVal,oldVal){
          if(newVal !== oldVal){
            $(element).stop().slideToggle(slideDuration);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  })
```

I'm brand new to angular so I'm sure it's something I'm misunderstanding, likely with scope.

Comment: Where's your closing </aside> tag supposed to be?

Comment: Are you using a version of Angular prior to 1.2?

Comment: 1.1.5 - The `/aside` is missing from the sample code due to my attempt to remove code that was extra, it's there in the real code after the content.

Comment: Are you in a position to try 1.2 or greater?  The way isolate scopes changed dramatically then, and they now work closer to way your code assumes they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular directives create their own scope, so if you place the anchor tag inside of the directive it will belong to the directive's scope, not the parent. To allow the directive to have access to a parent function you have to pass that function to the directive by adding it to the scope:

```
scope:{
    isOpen: "=slideToggle",
    onToggle: '&'
  }
```

And then manage the ng-click from inside of your directive. I would suggest something like this:

html

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <aside on-toggle="onToggle()" data-slide-toggle="smToggleSidebar" data-slide-toggle-duration="100">
        <a ng-click="onToggle()">&lang;</a>
        // content here
    </aside>
</div>
```

directive

```
.directive('slideToggle', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  scope:{
    isOpen: "=slideToggle",
    onToggle: "&"
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    var slideDuration = parseInt(attr.slideToggleDuration, 10) || 200;
    scope.$watch('isOpen', function(newVal,oldVal){
      if(newVal !== oldVal){
        $(element).stop().slideToggle(slideDuration);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

});

parent controller

```
$scope.onToggle = function(){
    $scope.smToggleSidebar =! $scope.smToggleSidebar;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it. Can you help me understand what part the `onToggle: "&"` does?

Comment: Note that this only true prior to version 1.2:  [fix($compile): make isolate scope truly isolate](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7)

Comment: Glad it worked. There are three ways of binding data to directives, '=' which is a two way binding (you use it in '=slideToggle'), '@' which is one way (parent to child) and '&' which is to allow access to parent functions. You can read more about it in the angular directive documentation http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: KayakDave is right though, I've been working with 1.0.8 for the last few months, but good to know that change happened.